# django-bower: Static files to be loaded by BowerFinder not found

Tags: django, bower, django-staticfiles, static-files

For some reason, the static files which are to be loaded by `djangobower.finders.BowerFinder` are not loading (getting a 404 Not Found in the server)

*settings.py*

```
STATIC_ROOT = "/root/Desktop/django-DefectDojo/static/"

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ()

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',
)

BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = '/root/Desktop/django-DefectDojo/components/'

BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'jquery-ui',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'djangobower',
)
```

*template*

```
<script src="{% static "jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js" %}"></script>
```

*project structure*

```
-project root
    -static
    -components
        -vendor
            -assets
                -bower-components
                    -jquery-ui
                        -jquery-ui.min.js
```

I do a `./manage.py bower install` followed by a `./manage.py collectstatic`

Now, on running the server, I get a Not Found.

However, when I make `STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/root/Desktop/django-DefectDojo/components/vendor/assets/bower_components/',)` then the static files get loaded.
But this shouldn't be the case as `BowerFinder` is supposed to be doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this is not a one-off instance. This occurs when `django-bower`'s `finders.py` is unable to locate either of the `bower_components` or the `components` directories in the provided `BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT` variable - which is what it looks for.

It is unable to do so because `bower install` now creates the `bower_components` directory as follows:

```
-projectroot
    -components
        -vendors
            -assets
                -bower_components
                    -
                    -
```

as against:

```
-projectroot
    -components
        -bower_components
            -
            -
```

The easiest way to resolve this is to set `BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'components\vendors\assets')` as opposed to doing just `BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'components')`

Related post from `django-bower`'s repo:
https://github.com/nvbn/django-bower/issues/20

Answer (score 0):

Bower created the `bower_components` directly in my Django root directory.
Therefore I just had to do this in the `settings.py`:

```
BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = BASE_DIR
```

Comment: Bowser? did you mean Bower?